# When player client starts to play a dash media

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, mp4, mpeg-dash

I'm working on Android Player for playing dash media.

In order to enable video starting fast, I preload a part of dash media, now the size of preload is 600kb.

As you see, 600kb is a magic number. In my opinion, different size should be preloaded for different dash file.

**All start position of dash media is 0.**

I want to know: How to know the size of dash media which can support player starts to play?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

MPGE DASH is an ABR format and it consists of a manifest or index file and associated media files.

The manifest, the '.mpd file, is a relatively small text file which provides pointers to the actual audio, video, subtitle etc media files.

For video, there are typically different bandwidth versions of the video available, each segmented into equal length, timewsie, chunks so the player can switch between bandwidth versions for the next chunk of the video depending on the network conditions and the device type.

The manifest file itself is not a standard length as there are different formats and information that can be included, and a live manifest may actually be updated every couple of seconds as the live stream progresses.

Hence, unless you control the headend yourself and can dictate the manifest format and size, there is no easy way to know in advance exactly how long a manifest will be.

The media streams are more predictable - for a given bandwidth version you can estimate the download size, and this is part of the work players do to decide the bandwidth of the next segment to download.